# system() alternative for Windows

Tags: c, exec, system, createprocess

On Windows it opens a console window that I'd like to get rid of. I want another function that is capable, without exception, of all the same things system() can do, but without that nasty command prompt comng up. I'm making an extension for GameMaker: Studio that does everything I need it to on Linux and Mac as they don't append opening a terminal window with system(). But since Windows works a bit differently with that function, I'm really stuck.

I've tried googling all over for solutions like ShellExecute or CreateProcess but neither of those are what I'm looking for. I want to be able to do DOS/Run Commands. A couple small examples

```
md c:\new_folder\
```

or

```
start notepad.exe
```

Stuff like that while also supporting multiple arguments. I've seen one possibilty is exec() but it replaces the current process, which on Windows there is no fork() function so I'm not sure how to use exec() how I'd like it to work without a fork() equivalent handy. I'd like to also give the user the ability to choose whether to wait for finishing. For example

```
// waits for notepad to close before going back to initial application.
SomeCustomFunction("notepad.exe", true);

// does not wait for notepad to close before resume.
SomeCustomFunction("notepad.exe", false);
```

On Linux, I wrote an *.SO library that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern "C"
{
    double SomeCustomFunction(char *fname,double wait)
    {
        if (wait < 1)
        {
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                system(fname);
                exit(0);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            system(fname);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It throws two warnings in Code::Blocks, but it compiles fine and works exactly how I want it to when I call the library from my GameMaker: Studio game / program.

Here's my attempt at the "Windows equivalent" (*.DLL):

```
#include "main.h"
#define DLL extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)

DLL double SomeCustomFunction(char *fname,double wait)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;

    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;

    ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo;

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, fname,
        NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,
        NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo))
    {
        if (wait >=1)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
        }

        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, on Windows, with the way I have it set up, it doesn't accept the same kind of stuff I'd like it to do, as mentioned earlier in this post.

I would use something like spawn() instead of CreateProcess(), but spawn() requires a separate string and argument for the filename and arguments, which I'd prefer to be all in one string / argument like in my Linux library function.

Thanks

Comment: _"but neither of those are what I'm looking for. I want to be able to do DOS/Run Commands"_ In how far doesn't `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecuted()` don't support this?

Comment: start notepad.exe doesn't work in CreateProcess but removing "start" and just have notepad works. Also I've tried using CreateProcess to make a new directory with "md new_folder" in the second argument and it didn't do anything. I'll provide my code snippet tomorrow. It's getting pretty late and I need to hit the hay.

Comment: Its probably you not using these functions right, not that these cannot do what you want to achieve. Refer to the documentation first please.

Comment: You might like to have a look at `spawn()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx

Comment: I updated the OP. Hope this helps.